# Is there a way to concatenate two field values on each new record when importing a spreadsheet in Access 2010?

Tags: excel, ms-access, import, concatenation, ms-access-2010

I'm looking to create a unique value for each record when importing from a spreadsheet by concatenating two different fields values from each newly imported row. I want to avoid doing it in Excel to simplify and automate the process. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make an advanced import filter, unless you program it by hand on VBA.

What you can do is create a calculated field where you join (concatenate) the two columns you want together. That calculated field (the new column you make) will apply to all rows and won't affect your database size.

After importing your columns into a new table, go into Design View and create a new column with whatever identifier you like.
This new column should be of type "Calculated". You will get into the Expression Builder where you will just select your two columns and use the concatenate operator:

```
[ColumnName1]&[ColumnName2]
```

Hope this helps out.

Comment: How does one create a "calculated" field in Access?

Comment: I have updated my answer clarifying it. Hope it helps better.